# Impresspages Recovery Page Event

Tags: plugins, impresspages

What's the event that catch the System->Recovery page action. we have `ipPageMarkedAsDeleted`, `ipPageRemoved` and `ipPageAdded`, for instance. Is there anything like `ipPageRecovery`. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event. You can add one and suggest a pull request.